What is the difference between passing NULL vs. nullptr to a template parameter?
I'm dealing with a fairly uniform vendor-provided API, and would like to check -- and handle -- any failures in a unified fashion too. To that end, I wrote the following wrapper:
template <typename Func, typename... Args>
auto awrap(Func &func, Args&&... args)
{
    auto code = func(args...);

    if (code >= 0)
        return code;

    ... handle the error ...
};
...
awrap(handlepath, handle, path, NULL, 0, coll, NULL);

The above compiles fine with clang, but g++13 -- and Microsoft VC++ -- both complain about the two NULL-arguments:
... error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
   87 |                 auto code = func(args...

Replacing the two NULLs with nullptr solves the problem, but why does it matter?
Likely, the NULL is turned into 0x0 or even 0 somewhere by the preprocessor, but the original call never raised an "eyebrow". Using NULL was perfectly suitable in:
handlepath(handle, path, NULL, 0, coll, NULL);

Why is it a problem (for some compilers), when used in a wrapper?

UPDATE: the /usr/include/sys/_null.h on my FreeBSD system has the following code:
#ifndef NULL

#if !defined(__cplusplus)
#define NULL    ((void *)0)
#else
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
#define NULL    nullptr
#elif defined(__GNUG__) && defined(__GNUC__) && __GNUC__ >= 4
#define NULL    __null
#else
#if defined(__LP64__)
#define NULL    (0L)
#else
#define NULL    0
#endif  /* __LP64__ */
#endif  /* __GNUG__ */
#endif  /* !__cplusplus */

#endif

So:

for C, NULL is (void *)0;

for clang++ NULL and nullptr are the same thing, whereas for GNU it may not be...



NULL is implementation defined and may be defined to be 0 (for legacy situations) or nullptr (better).  But perhaps you intended nullptr anyway?  In other words, what is your motivation for using NULL at all?

The function being wrapped -- the handlepath() -- is a C one, and all of the vendor-provided examples are using NULL.

constexpr auto ø = nullptr; now you can use ø.

If using modern C++, consider NULL deprecated. It is only maintained for backward compatiblity with C. If you don't intend to compile against C, just use nullptr; it is safer in terms of unintentional integer casting.

In both C and (by reference to C) C++, NULL is only required to expand to a null pointer constant which is a value that compares equal to zero - the type is not specified.  In practice, some implementations define it as 0 or 0L or similar, so it has an integral type, but others define it to have a pointer type (e.g. it expands to (void *)0).    In C++, nullptr is guaranteed to have a type std::nullptr_t, which can be implicitly coverted to a pointer.    This matters for template parameter packs, since they don't do any implicit conversions (e.g. to convert a 0 to a pointer).

In many implementations, NULL is just a #define for an integer literal 0, eg:
#define NULL 0

You can directly assign a literal 0 to any pointer, which is why passing NULL directly to the target function works fine.
Since you are passing NULL to a template parameter, that parameter is being deduced as type int, as the error message says.
In this call:
awrap(handlepath, handle, path, NULL, 0, coll, NULL);

awrap() will resolve to something like this:
auto awrap(decltype(handlepath) &func, decltype(handle) arg1, decltype(path) arg2,
    int arg3, int arg4, decltype(coll) arg5, int arg6)
 // ^^^^^^^^                                 ^^^^^^^^
{
    auto code = func(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6);
    //                    error: ^^^^       error: ^^^^
    ...
};

To assign an int variable to a pointer, you need an explicit type-cast, which you are not using.
Whereas nullptr is of type nullptr_t, which can also be assigned directly to any pointer.  There is only 1 possible value of nullptr_t. So, when passing nullptr to a template parameter, that parameter will be deduced as type nullptr_t. And the compiler knows how to assign a nullptr_t to a pointer.
In this call:
awrap(handlepath, handle, path, nullptr, 0, coll, nullptr);

awrap() will resolve to something like this:
auto awrap(decltype(handlepath) &func, decltype(handle) arg1, decltype(path) arg2,
    nullptr_t arg3, int arg4, decltype(coll) arg5, nullptr_t arg6)
 // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    auto code = func(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6);
    //                       OK: ^^^^          OK: ^^^^
    ...
};

So, when calling your template, you should use nullptr.
But, if you want to use NULL then you must type-cast it as (char*)NULL (or equivalent), or whatever other pointer type the parameter is expecting, eg:
awrap(handlepath, handle, path, (char*)NULL, 0, coll, (char*)NULL);


Still don't understand, why passing that NULL was Ok before the wrapping. And, why clang is not even warning (much less erroring) here...

Upvoted after seeing "In many implementations".  Thanks for appropriately qualifying that.

@MikhailT. as I explained, passing a literal 0 to a pointer works. So, passing NULL directly to a pointer parameter of the original function will work. But, your wrapper is adding a level of indirection, you are no longer passing a literal 0 directly to the original function's pointer parameter. You are now passing NULL to a (deduced) int wrapper parameter, and than passing that int to the original function's pointer parameter. Which does not work without a typecast.

"(char*)NULL (aka reinterpret_cast<char*>(0))": That's not correct. (char*)NULL will resolve to static_cast<char*>(NULL) which uses an implicit conversion. In fact reinterpret_cast<char*>(0) is technically not guaranteed to behave as expected. It is not required that reinterpret_cast<char*>(0) produces a null pointer value. That's also why (char*)arg inside the function would be problematic and too late for the conversion. nullptr really is the only clean solution here.

@RemyLebeau static_cast<char*>(0) must compile and behaves exactly like the implicit conversion of 0 to char*. reinterpret_cast<char*>(0) has a distinct behavior than the two.

@MikhailT. This basically boils down to the difference between char* foo = 0; and int i = 0; char* foo = i;.  Since NULL is just a macro that expands to the literal 0, the former is what you had before the template wrapper and the latter is what you have afterwards.

NULL is a macro which can either be defined as nullptr or as a zero-valued integer literal (e.g. 0 or 0L). Which one is implementation-defined, but because only the latter choice is valid in C and pre-C++11 the chances of seeing the latter are good.
nullptr is an object of nullptr_t. Any expression of this type is always a so-called null pointer constant, meaning that it can be implicitly converted to a null pointer value of any pointer type.
A zero-valued integer expression however is not always a null pointer constant. Specifically only null-valued integer literals are null pointer constants that can be converted to pointer types.
So, if you pass 0 directly to a function expecting a char* that works out fine, the literal 0 is a null pointer constant and can be converted to a the pointer type implicitly, resulting in a null pointer value.
But you are passing the literal on to awrap as integer type (by deduction). When you use the argument in func(args...) it is still an integer expression with value zero, but it is not an integer literal. Therefore the argument is not a null pointer constant and can't be implicitly converted to char*.
So, you can't pass 0 for a pointer parameter through the wrapper because you must name the literal exactly where the conversion should apply. And whether you can use NULL is implementation-defined. It works if NULL happens to be defined as nullptr, but not if it is a zero-valued integer literal.
That's a good example why only nullptr should be used. The implicit conversion behavior of zero-valued integer literals exists only for historical reasons inherited from C. If the language was designed today, I doubt that anyone would add such a weird special case to conversions. Normally the possible conversions are determined by type and value category of expressions. This is the only special case where the value and the grammatical construction affect conversion behavior.

It also takes C++ yet another step further from C...

@MikhailT. C23 now also has nullptr. I think my last paragraph should apply to C as well.

What's wrong with (void *)0 for C?

@MikhailT. There is a quite a bit of rationale in https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3042.htm. But it also still suffers the same weirdness I mentioned in my answer for C++: In C, only specifically an integer constant expression of value 0 or an integer constant expression of value 0 cast to void* specifically are null pointer constants that safely convert to null pointer values. In contrast to C++ implicit conversion to pointer types is always possible, but the result may not be guaranteed.
